# ¿cómo hago para comparar si un registro existe?

Tags: php, html5

Estoy haciendo una pagina de ventas.
lo que quiero hacer es que si existe el registro me redireccione a otra pagina, sin embargo, no lo hace.
aunque en mi formulario ingrese un registro que yo se que existe, me dice que el usuario no existe.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```php
<?php

include('conexion.php');

$correo = isset($_POST['correo']);
$contra = isset($_POST['contraseña']);
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo' AND contraseña = '$contra'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);


if ($resultado && mysqli_num_rows($resultado)>0) {
    header("location: /flamestore/pagina-principal/pagina-principal.php");
}
else{

    echo"usuario no encontrado";
}



?>
```

Comment: Tu código como texto por favor

Comment: Prueba cambiando tu `SELECT * FROM....` por `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` para que esta segunda te devuelva un valor numérico

Comment: ¿Guardas las contraseñas en "texto plano"? Esta es una **muy mala práctica**.

Comment: Las contraseñas las guardo con type password, no se si te refieras a eso

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema radica en que en el SELECT estás usando la ñ para contraseña.

Comprueba si poniendo:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo' AND contrase%ñ%a = '$contra'";
```

ó

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo' AND contrase'%ñ%'a = '$contra'";
```

te funciona como debe.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que el isset no lo uses en una asignación, ya que lo que estás haciendo es asignando un valor booleano a la variable segun lo que venga en el POST, también lo que te han dicho de no utilizar la ñ tomalo en cuenta y por último en el form de ingreso puedes agregar validaciones para evitar que se haga el submit sin informacion, espero que asi te sirva:

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');

if(isset($_POST["correo"]) && isset($_POST["contraseña"])){

$correo = trim($_POST["correo"]);
$contra = trim($_POST["contraseña"]);
$consulta = "sELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='".$correo."' AND contraseña = '".$contra."';";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

if($resultado === FALSE)
    {
        die(print_r(mysqli_error(), TRUE));
    }

else 
{
    header("location: /flamestore/pagina-principal/pagina-principal.php");
}

    echo "usuario no encontrado";

}

else {
    echo "No se han ingresado datos";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo a la hora de hacer consultas con nombres de campos, que sean palabras reservadas de mysql o que tengan caracteres especiales como *Ñ* que utilices las comillas invertidas para ese campo o todos:

`` `contraseña` ``
Ese caracter podes ponerlo con "ALT+96"